# Third order Taylor polynomial of function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function $f$ in two variables which is at least $3$ times continuously differentiable, it's Taylor polynomial of second order at $x=x_0$ is given by $T(f,x) = f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)^T(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^TH(x-x_0)$, whereby $H$ is the Hessian matrix. I want to find the third order Taylor polynomial of $f$. I am struggling to find the third order derivative written as an array just like one would show the Hessian matrix. I am aware that it should be a (symmetric) tensor, but given the simple case of $2$ variables, I thought it will be not difficult to represent it as an array. Can somebody show that array in this particular case ? I know how the third derivative terms look like in the Taylor polynomial. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any particularly nice notation in the form of arrays. We need a cubic form, which has three indices, and while vectors ($\nabla f$) and matrices ($H$) have only so many indices that we can use the two dimensions given by a piece of paper, three indices would require one more dimension to write them down as arrays in such a way that it's actually useful.